# Need Haar Cascades For Cars

Tags: xml, python-2.7, detection, opencv3.0

I'm working on car detection.Working on python and open cv3.

So I need examples for cars.xml. There are too many xml files that contains eye, face, human body but couldn't find haar cascades for cars.

Answer (score 3):

It takes some searching but there are existing haar cascades for cars (although I agree that there are fewer than for faces, eyes etc). I quickly googled it and came across a couple of GitHub repositories, here is a link to one of them (I can't post any more than that as my rep is too low):

https://github.com/abhi-kumar/CAR-DETECTION/blob/master/cas4.xml

Be warned that they might not be exactly as you require and so you may find yourself having to add your own data to supplement the cascades in the links. You could follow the excellent tutorials on [Python Programming](https://pythonprogramming.net/haar-cascade-object-detection-python-opencv-tutorial/) to work out how to build your own. Good luck!